# Heat kernel on complex space

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, complex-numbers

Let
G be the Heat Kernel

$G(t,x)=[4\pi t]^{-\frac{N}{2}}e^{-|x|^{2}/(4t)}$

$(t>0)$

$u_0(x) \in \mathbb C ^d$

$u_0 \in L^{\infty}$
and $u(t)=G(t)*u_0$

$w \in \mathbb C ^d$

Is it true that $Re(\bar w. u(t)) \leq Re( \bar w. u_0)$?

How can I bound the convolution?